# Alternative of iface for standalone PyQGIS application

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

To know the active layer and the attribute of the qgis project, I'm using the iface variable in the integrated Python console.
But I want to achieve this information through a standalone Python script. So how to retrieve the information (activelayer, attribute, features, etc) without the iface.
As per my understanding iface variable will work for the integrated Python console in QGIS.

Comment: How would you define an active layer without the interface?

Comment: No need an interface to get active layer in standalone PyQGIS application.

Answer (score 10):

`iface` is predefined variable in QGIS. It is defined while QGIS starts and refers to QGIS interface. That means you cannot use `iface` in your standalone application.

You can use `QgsProject.instance()` to get the attributes of a project in your application.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
```

To get the active layer use the script below:

```
def activeLayer():
    project = QgsProject.instance()

    tree_root = project.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    tree_model = QgsLayerTreeModel(tree_root)
    tree_view = QgsLayerTreeView()
    tree_view.setModel(tree_model)

    return tree_view.currentLayer()


active_layer = activeLayer()
```

If you would like to use other methods of `iface` you should similarly define them in your application, like `activeLayer` above.

Comment: If i use the idea of the script it gives me an error "cannot import name 'QgsLayerTreeView' from 'qgis.core". Any thing I forgot?

Comment: @miraculix, very late comment- but `QgsLayerTreeView` is part of gui library not core. So: `from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeView`