# PyQGIS `iface` object for layer event handling in QGIS plugin testing

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm writing a functional test for the QGIS plugin I'm developing. There's a button in the plugin that is enabled only if there is a valid vector layer present. The thing I'm bumping into is the layer event handling from a standard lib unittest isn't triggering the button enable as expected. When I test manually, the button is enabled fine, but from the test it isn't.

My test setup is pretty straightforward:

```py
import unittest

from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer

from namari_dockwidget import NamariDockWidget

app = QgsApplication(argv=[], GUIenabled=True)
app.initQgis()


class NamariDockWidgetTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.dock_widget = NamariDockWidget()

    def test_dockwidget_layer_selector(self) -> None:
        with self.subTest('When we start the widget, there is no layer set'):
            self.assertTrue(self.dock_widget.isEnabled())

            layer = self.dock_widget.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
            self.assertEqual(layer, None)

        with self.subTest('So the "Build model" button is disabled'):
            enabled = self.dock_widget.pushButtonBuildModel.isEnabled()
            self.assertFalse(enabled)

        with self.subTest('But when we load a vector data source'):
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(
                path='test/data/amersfoort-centre.gpkg',
                baseName='amersfoort-centre',
                providerLib='ogr')

            self.assertEqual(len(layer.fields()), 10)

            # Load the vector layer
            self.dock_widget.iface.addMapLayer(layer)

        with self.subTest('Then the build button is enabled'):
            enabled = self.dock_widget.pushButtonBuildModel.isEnabled()
            self.assertTrue(enabled)
```

However the last assertion fails: the button is not enabled once the layer is added through the `iface` object (that I learned from [this excellent question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388870/how-to-call-qgisinterface-class-in-a-plugin)). Any idea on what I'm missing?

To reproduce: the current state of the plugin is in https://github.com/reinvantveer/namari/tree/button_test_issue-alpha2. There's a very helpful Dockerile that can help you get up and running the test within minutes: just run `docker build .`, but there's also the output of the associated GitHub action build at https://github.com/reinvantveer/namari/runs/2208580233.

EDIT: I now see that I only loaded the UI elements from the NamariDockWidget, but this does not include the Namari class I wrote for the logic. Somehow, I need access to the QGIS `iface` object from within my unit test, but how does this work?

The plugin logic class begins like

```
# ...
class Namari:
    def __init__(self, iface: QgisInterface) -> None:
```

So a lot of the logic depends on the `iface` object being available. But I have currently no way of strapping a class instance to my test.

Comment: It appears I missed something obvious as well: the QGIS widget does not have an `iface` object either: https://github.com/reinvantveer/namari/runs/2208580233#step:3:176 but now I'm faced with the question how to enable this

Comment: This appears to be a tricky question: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/3776

Comment: Also related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380678/alternative-of-iface-for-standalone-pyqgis-application but no solution to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an almost duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71206/writing-automated-tests-for-qgis-plugins), with an answer that put me on the right track.

The answer is also a lot more involved than I had imagined. So much more that I decided to write a post about it [here](https://reinvantveer.github.io/2021/04/10/qgis-plugin-development.html).

The upshot: use the `qgis_testrunner.sh` script from the official [QGIS docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/qgis/qgis/tags) to run a Python test script containing a `def run_all()` function.

Comment: I think you can now approve your own answer to properly "close" this question.

Comment: Thank you @GermánCarrillo