# iface as NoneType object in OSGeo4W shell

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, osgeo4w

I'm trying to run a PyQGIS script in OSGeo4W shell. Previously, I imported all the necessary modules:

```
from qgis.core import *    
from qgis.utils import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

but when I want to use iface (iface.activeLayer() for example), I get this:
[image: NoneType object]

In OSGeo4W shell the output of the dir command is:
[image: dir(iface) in OSGeo4W Shell]

And in QGIS python console the output of the dir command is:
[image: dir(iface) in QGIS Python console]

Is there any possibility to fix this problem?

Comment: The `iface` variable is not available in standalone scripts. Maybe this  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380678/alternative-of-iface-for-standalone-pyqgis-application can help?

Comment: Please do not include text/code as images.